# How to keep window on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, always-on-top

I am wondering if there is an easy way to keep this popup window (span) JPicker (built on JQuery) on top of other modal windows or divs? Zindex, is there a way to make sure the zindex is always on top?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the [z-index](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) to a very large value, say 9999, that will essentially guarantee that the window is the top-most.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS. Worked for me in my jQ Dialogs.

```
.jPicker{z-index:2000 !important;}
```

!important overrides the default z-index which is 10 or 20 I think.